# Cause of No component found with scheme: ftp

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I am experimenting with Spring Boot and Camel.  I have a simple route:

```
@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("ftp://localhost/INBOUND?username=blah&password=foo")
                .to("file:/tmp/test");
    }
}
```

My pom file has:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.3</version>
</dependency>
```

On startup I get the following error:

> Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route2: Route(route2)[[From[ftp://localhost/INBOUND?username=blah... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: ftp://localhost/INBOUND?password=set42now&username=comcast due to: No component found with scheme: ftp

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `camel-ftp-starter` dependency name.

Comment: Yes, you need the `camel-ftp-started` dependency.

Comment: Using camel-ftp-starter did work, but I also had to remove my dependency on camel-spring-boot-starter.  I have a new question, but I will put that in another post when I have done more research.  If someone want to officially answer this question, I will accept the answer and give them credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `camel-ftp-starter` dependency instead of `camel-ftp`.